# xls.part could not be saved, because the source file could not be read

Tags: c#, excel, google-chrome, firefox, download

I am trying to download an exel file using the code but firefox is giving the above mention error.

Answer (score 1):

You need to build a  file first, then pass it to you Context.Current.Response.
Here you just write some content directly in the response.

Comment: Do you have some idea that what code is useful to build.. I shall be very thankful to you.

Comment: Do you still have this problem ?  / need a response ?